# What tools are there to convert a PHP web app into a Desktop application?

Tags: php, web-applications, desktop-application

I have developed a website for a hospital. Now I want change the website into a Windows application.
What tools exist for converting a PHP, JavaScript, HTML and CSS website into a Windows Desktop application?

Comment: You´ll need to learn a new programming language. like C# or C++.

Comment: [Click here before you post your next question.](http://s.tk/onhold)

Comment: Seems like some projects exists but I never try it myself... https://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop/

Comment: @Daan Well, [not strictly true](https://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop/) but yeah, either of those langs would be streets ahead of PHP for desktop

Comment: What you want to accomplish is not a straightforward process. The software/technologies that powers your site is designed for its task (websites) while most desktop applications are designed for theirs (applications). It's true the lines have gotten blurry over time because the web was feeble at first and has evolved tremendously now being able to support full blown web-applications of its own. But the differences in structure / design / communications are still big enough to make conversion from one to another pretty difficult.

Comment: This means that a lot of things need to be considered when designing the initial application to ensure that it can be used as either desktop or local application. Usually this entails breaking your application into 3 components -- the desktop interface, the web interface and the server. Checkout platforms such as Adobe Air -- they use HTML/CSS/JS to build user interfaces -- with this or other similar projects you could reuse some or most of your web interface when creating your desktop interface.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has it's own library for desktop applications. You can read about it [here](http://devzone.zend.com/1129/developing-desktop-applications-in-php-for-beginners/)

Comment: Last stable release was 6 years ago.